# How to Calculate Percentage Using Computed Column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I was trying to calculate percentage using computed column. By adding below MS Sql query into cumputed column.

```
  Select (([Apple]*100) / (NULLIF([Apple]+[Samsung]+[Vivo]+[MI]+[oppo]+[Oneplus],0))) As PerOfApple  
  From [dbo].[CellPhone]
```

But i'm getting null values in every row of (PerOfApple )column after execution of this query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need `coalesce()`:

```
Select ([Apple] * 100.0) /
        NULLIF(coalesce([Apple], 0) + coalesce([Samsung], 0) + coalesce([Vivo], 0) + coalesce([MI], 0) + coalesce([oppo], 0) +coalesce([Oneplus], 0), 0)
        )  As PerOfApple
From [dbo].[CellPhone];
```

Note that I replaced the `100` with `100.0`.  SQL Server does integer division and that might not be desirable for this computation.